# Weka Model to Prediction

Tags: weka

I have generated two source code for two different model from training set  for a classifier in Weka. 
Is there any way through which I can combine these two different models generated from the same Weka Classifier?

Any suggestions or solutions would be of great help.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in detail? What do you mean when you say "combine"? Output in the same file? Use output of one file in another? A small script example would be helpful.

Comment: Sure. Thank you. When I say "combine" I need to find/build a new model from the two models generated individually from two different data sets.

Comment: Why dont you apply a third one model, and voted them all?
like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020799/weka-classifier-meta-vote

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to combine two or more classifiers into a single classifier. Weka offers schemes such as vote and stacking (`weka.classifiers.meta`). Boosting and bagging schemes (such as Adaboost) are technically also ways of combining multiple classifiers into one, but they typically work around a single type of classifier and help you train it more intensively.

When using vote you can include multiple classifiers, each of which assign a class to an instance. Vote itself will assign the class that was assigned most often. Stacking trains a meta classifier over the included classifiers. In a way it helps you train a way of interpreting multiple classifications.

You can accomplish that in the Weka Explorer (classification tab), by selecting the pre build models under preBuildClassifiers, or setting them in your code with `setPreBuiltClassifiers`.